# Prevent from clicking, change class name, hide the highlight - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, button, highlight

I have a three issue in this app.

**First** issue is that the show button doesn't change its name to "show offer" when the app is closed after we open it.

**Second**, the app doesn't prevent a user from clicking second and third button. He can click only one offer, but now the user can click on every.

**Third**, the user can highlight a new offer by clicking once, then he can hide the highlight, but cannot highlight it again and never. Appreciate any help.

```js
//// hide offer before the Dom is loaded
//$('ul').hide()
$(document).ready(function() {   
    
    function showHideOffer() {
        $('ul').slideToggle();
    }
    
    //click to show offers
    $('.card').on('click', '.showOffers', showHideOffer, function() {
       $('.showOffers').html('Hide Offers');
    });
    
    //click to hide offers - change name to show offers doesn't work!!
    $('.card').on('click','.showOffers', showHideOfferfunction() {
   $('.showOffers').html('Show Offers');
});
    
    // click to book, to show info and close button and span
   $('li').on('click', 'button', function(){
      var offerName = $(this).closest('.tour').data('name');
      var offerPrice = $(this).closest('.tour').data('price')
      var message = $('<ol class="breadcrumb"><li class="breadcrumb-item active" style="color:#3CB371">Success! You have booked '+offerName+' offer for '+offerPrice+'!</li></ol>');
       $(this).closest('.tour').append(message);
       
       $(this).prev().closest('.details').remove();
       $(this).remove();     
   });
    
    // filter new offers by clicking a "new" button
    $('#buttons').on('click','.filterNew', function() {
            $('.tour').filter('.newOffer').addClass('highlightnew');
            $('.highlightpopular').removeClass('highlightpopular');
               //click second time and the highlight is hidden
               $('#buttons').on('click', '.filterNew', function() {
                    $('.highlightnew').removeClass('highlightnew');
                });
        });
    
        // filter by popular offers
        $('#buttons').on('click', '.filterPopular', function() { 
            $('.tour').filter('.popular').addClass('highlightpopular');
            $('.highlightnew').removeClass('highlightnew');
        });
    
    
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>GuidedTours</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="wageup.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <style>
          .selected {
            color: red;
          }
          .highlightnew {
            background: #3D9970;
          }
            .highlightpopular {
                background: #39CCCC;
            }
            ul {
                display:none;
            }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
       <h2>Guided Tours</h2>
            <hr>
            <div id="tours" class="card">
                <!-- click to show -->
                <button type="button" value="Show Offers" class="btn showOffers btn-primary btn-sm">Show Offers</button>
                
              <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <li class="usa tour newOffer list-group-item"; data-name="New York" data-price="$550">
                  <h3>New York, New York</h3>
                  <span class="details badge badge-success">$1,899 for 7 nights</span>
                  <button class="book btn btn-primary">Book Now</button>
                </li>

                <li class="europe tour newOffer list-group-item" data-name="Paris" data-price="$450">
                  <h3>Paris, France</h3>
                  <span class="details badge badge-success">$2,299 for 7 nights</span>
                  <button class="book btn btn-primary">Book Now</button>
                </li>

                <li class="asia tour popular list-group-item" data-name="Tokyo" data-price="$650">
                  <h3>Tokyo, Japan</h3>
                  <span class="details badge badge-success">$3,799 for 7 nights</span>
                  <button class="book btn btn-primary">Book Now</button>
                </li>
              </ul>
                <ul id="buttons" class="list-group list list-group-flush">
                <button class="filterNew btn btn-info">New</button>
                <button class="filterPopular btn btn-info">Popular</button>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>





        <!-- Scripts -->

        <!-- Jquery -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- JS -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="guidedtours.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't have any bugs, you are just NOT asking your code to do it ^^

Comment: I can provide bugs if you want it, but I removed it for the purpose of the clean code.

Comment: I try to be clearer, you aren't asking your code to change again the name of show offers, for example

Comment: I added for you my only idea of solving it, but this now blocking the code to run.

Answer (score 0):

**First Issue Solve : Checkout Here :**
Change the code to

```
$('.card').on('click', '.showOffers', showHideOffer, function() {
       //$('.showOffers').html('');

       $(this).text( $(this).text() == 'Hide Offers' ? "Show Offers" : "Hide Offers");
    });
```

**Instead Of :**

```
$('.card').on('click', '.showOffers', showHideOffer, function() {
       $('.showOffers').html('Hide Offers');
    });
```

```js
    
    
    //click to show offers
    $('.card').on('click', '.showOffers', showHideOffer, function() {
       //$('.showOffers').html('');
       
       $(this).text( $(this).text() == 'Hide Offers' ? "Show Offers" : "Hide Offers");
    });
    
    //click to hide offers - change name to show offers doesn't work!!
   $('.card').on('click','.showOffers', showHideOffer);
    
    // click to book, to show info and close button and span
   $('li').on('click', 'button', function(){
      var offerName = $(this).closest('.tour').data('name');
      var offerPrice = $(this).closest('.tour').data('price')
      var message = $('<ol class="breadcrumb"><li class="breadcrumb-item active" style="color:#3CB371">Success! You have booked '+offerName+' offer for '+offerPrice+'!</li></ol>');
       $(this).closest('.tour').append(message);
       
       $(this).prev().closest('.details').remove();
       $(this).remove();     
   });
    
    // filter new offers by clicking a "new" button
    $('#buttons').on('click','.filterNew', function() {
            $('.tour').filter('.newOffer').addClass('highlightnew');
            $('.highlightpopular').removeClass('highlightpopular');
               //click second time and the highlight is hidden
               $('#buttons').on('click', '.filterNew', function() {
                    $('.highlightnew').removeClass('highlightnew');
                });
        });
    
        // filter by popular offers
        $('#buttons').on('click', '.filterPopular', function() { 
            $('.tour').filter('.popular').addClass('highlightpopular');
            $('.highlightnew').removeClass('highlightnew');
        });
    
    
function showHideOffer() {
        $('ul').slideToggle();
    }
```

```css
   .selected {
            color: red;
          }
          .highlightnew {
            background: #3D9970;
          }
            .highlightpopular {
                background: #39CCCC;
            }
            ul {
                display:none;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



    
    <div class="container">
       <h2>Guided Tours</h2>
            <hr>
            <div id="tours" class="card">
                <!-- click to show -->
                <button type="button" value="Show Offers" class="btn showOffers btn-primary btn-sm">Show Offers</button>
                
              <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <li class="usa tour newOffer list-group-item"; data-name="New York" data-price="$550">
                  <h3>New York, New York</h3>
                  <span class="details badge badge-success">$1,899 for 7 nights</span>
                  <button class="book btn btn-primary">Book Now</button>
                </li>

                <li class="europe tour newOffer list-group-item" data-name="Paris" data-price="$450">
                  <h3>Paris, France</h3>
                  <span class="details badge badge-success">$2,299 for 7 nights</span>
                  <button class="book btn btn-primary">Book Now</button>
                </li>

                <li class="asia tour popular list-group-item" data-name="Tokyo" data-price="$650">
                  <h3>Tokyo, Japan</h3>
                  <span class="details badge badge-success">$3,799 for 7 nights</span>
                  <button class="book btn btn-primary">Book Now</button>
                </li>
              </ul>
                <ul id="buttons" class="list-group list list-group-flush">
                <button class="filterNew btn btn-info">New</button>
                <button class="filterPopular btn btn-info">Popular</button>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: That's very wise solution for it. Thanks. Why do you put one parentheses in a condition and two in execution section?

Comment: it's my mistake.. you can also put in same code.. don't write two times.. It might taking overlap in execution

Answer (score 0):

```
To Resolve your first issue modify your function like below 
var ValuesShowOrHidden = 0;
$('.card').on('click', '.showOffers', showHideOffer, function () {
                if (ValuesShowOrHidden == 0) {
                    $('.showOffers').html('Hide Offers');
                    ValuesShowOrHidden = 1;

                }
                else if (ValuesShowOrHidden==1) {
                    $('.showOffers').html('Show Offers');
                    ValuesShowOrHidden = 0;
                }
            });
```

For the Second Issue try the below modification in your function

```
$('li').on('click', 'button', function () {


                var offerName = $(this).closest('.tour').data('name');
                var offerPrice = $(this).closest('.tour').data('price')
                var message = $('<ol class="breadcrumb"><li class="breadcrumb-item active" style="color:#3CB371">Success! You have booked ' + offerName + ' offer for ' + offerPrice + '!</li></ol>');
                $(this).closest('.tour').append(message);

                $(this).prev().closest('.details').remove();
                $(this).remove();
                $('li').unbind("click");
            });
```

Comment: Great way to handle the second issue, just with one line! Nice try with first issue, thanks. Do you have any idea for third problem?

Comment: your third issue is already resolved by making the links not clickable , user selects an offer and you show a green message there and after that user can't select any offer. user can hide and show offers but no more offer is selectable. do you want something else ?
Moreover this java script code is lots of dirty and complex to understand. i have just provided some quick solutions to your problem but overall this application is not gonna work this way. it looks like an assignment work. 
you can upvote the answer which satisfy your needs. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by dirty and complex to understand? Which part?